# hash_map value deletion

Tags: c++, hashmap

My question concern memory management.

I got this container :

```
typedef hash_map<const string, Powerdomain*, strptrhash, strptrequal> PowerdomainHashMap;
```

now I add one element in it

```
PowerdomainHashMap powerdomainMap;
Powerdomain* pd1=new Powerdomain("Powerdomain1");
powerdomainMap.insert(Powerdomain_pair(pd1->getName(),pd1));
```

After that my program does a first step.

Now that the first step is done, i no longer need the powerdomains and want to delete them.

Is a `powerdomainMap.clear()` sufficient ? Will it destroy all the  value entries in the map (ie call delete on every Powerdomain* in the map?

(I think it is better than calling delete on a iterator on the map but i am not sure)

Comment: You'd be better storing the Powerdomain pointers in a `shared_ptr` then they would automatically get deleted when you clear the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a `powerdomainMap.clear()` sufficient ?

No. You have manually acquired memory (using `new`), you need to manually release it (using `delete`). Better to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers though (preferably `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: do you got a link for an example on how to use std::shared_ptr ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud Hmm, Google spewed up this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsmartptr.aspx

Comment: there is question about std namespace, I was wondering when boost moved to STL.:-)

Comment: @Danil With the new standard (C++0x). All current compilers support `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 5):

No it won't - you need to iterate over the map and call delete on the contents yourself. Or better yet, use a map of smart pointers which will do the delete for you. Another alternative, if you don't need polymorphism, is to use a map of name to *values*, not pointers, in which case you can lose the dynamic memory management stuff altogether.

Comment: hm if i do this : 'for (PowerdomainHashMap::iterator powerdomainIterator(powerdomainMap.begin()),j=powerdomainMap.end();powerdomainIterator!=j;powerdomainIterator++){
  delete powerdomainIterator->second;
 }' it doesn't work as second return a copy of the value

Comment: Yes, but the copy is a pointer, so you can delete it. And is there anything wrong with calling your iterator `it`? Long names do not lead to readable code.